# How to not save image captured with camera in an self made folder?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent

**Hello everyone! I am using a camera which saves photo's in the phones gallery. But I don't want to save the photo in the gallery. I want to save it somewhere else. So all i need is not to save it automatically in the gallery.**

This is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView photo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button click = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnPhoto);
        photo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgPhoto);

        click.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data");
            photo.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
}
```

**If my question is not good enough, please ask me! And please help me out.**

Comment: [Taking photos](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html) and [Storing Photos or files](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html)

Answer (score 0):

This method for open camera and path is File declare global.

```
 private void openCamera() {
    Logger.i("openCamera");

    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(this.getPackageManager()) != null) {
        File rootPath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "folderName");
        if (!rootPath.exists())
            rootPath.mkdirs();

        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-kk-mm-ss");
        String snapshotImage = df.format(new Date()) + ".jpg";

        rootPath = new File(rootPath + "/" + snapshotImage);
        path = rootPath;

       takePictureIntent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(path));


        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    }

}
```

get result

```
  @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize = 8;



        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState())) {
            FileOutputStream fos = null;
            try {

              //  Float Latitude=0.0f, Longitude=0.0f;

                imageDvr.setImageURI(Uri.parse(path.getAbsolutePath()));



            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (fos != null) {
                    try {
                        fos.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                    }
                }
            }


        }


    }


}
```

and also give per\mission in manifest file

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will get the **bitmap** of image in **onActivityResult()**, and you will store that Image by bitmap.

Use below function to **store image** on **your self made folder**. you need to make that folder and need to use path of that.

like this.

```
public void SaveImage(Bitmap showedImgae){

String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
File myDir = new File(root + "/YourSelfMadeFolder");    
myDir.mkdirs();
Random generator = new Random();
int n = 10000;
n = generator.nextInt(n);
String fname = "FILENAME-"+ n +".jpg";
File file = new File (myDir, fname);
if (file.exists ()) file.delete (); 
try {
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
    showedImgae.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
    Toast.makeText(activityname.this, "Image Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    out.flush();
    out.close();

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add intent android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT with your URI:

```
    private File getOutputMediaFile() {
    File mediaStorageDir = null;
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

        if (state.contains(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
            mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment
                    .getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/yourFolderName");
        } else {
            mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment
                    .getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/yourFolderName");
        }

    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
        Logger.d("Desc", "File dir " + mediaStorageDir.mkdirs());
    }

    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());


        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
                "Image_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
    return mediaFile;
   }
```

your button click:

```
  click.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Uri mImageCaptureUri = null;
        File mediaFile = getOutputMediaFile();
        mImageCaptureUri = Uri.fromFile(mediaFile);

        intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mImageCaptureUri);
        intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        this.startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_TAKE_PICTURE);
}}0;
```

on activity result:

```
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

      Log.d("FilePath","Path"+mediaFile.getAbsolutePath();)
    }
```